# SSRS unable to send email via subscription

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2019

I have successfully configured email settings in SSRS. But sending email via subscription fails with error

> The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm

Only TLS 1.2 is enabled, other protocols are disabled on server.

Database mail is enabled and is working fine. What can cause that error in SSRS?